# Mutation testing for Emacs Lisp

Tags: testing

What is the practice of mutation testing in Emacs Lisp?

Source file in question is [haskell-indentation.el](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/blob/master/haskell-indentation.el)  with test suite in [haskell-indentation-tests.el](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/blob/master/tests/haskell-indentation-tests.el)

There are quite some strings in `haskell-indentation.el` and I'd like to have an overview how many of those are actually tested properly.

Note that we have line coverage already in place in [coveralls.io](https://coveralls.io/builds/5925167/source?filename=haskell-indentation.el).

Comment: There is such a practice?  I mean, aside from manually "mutating" your own code and seeing whether it fails...

Comment: I'd like to get over the 'manually' part.